# Does sitecore.cli require identity server?

Tags: identity-server, sso, sitecore-cli

When using the Sitecore CLI in SC10, the --authority parameter seems to require the identity server.  Can it be used without the identity server?  What would be the format of the URL?  We have SSO integrated into the Sitecore CM, and would like to continue to use that.

Comment: We have not tested with other identity providers, what SSO provider are you using?

Comment: We are using Okta SAML.  We wrote a provider for Okta for the CM (originally for SC9.0), because the documentation for building a provider for SI are pretty skinny, and the NuGet packages seem to be non-existent.  If I try to use the CM server --authority  https://sc100/, I get "Error connecting to https://sc100-sitecore.agninternet.com/.well-known/openid-configuration: Not Found"

Comment: Theoretically the `--auth` argument would point at Okta, but not something that's been attempted at all. I'm adding this to our backlog to evaluate for feasibility.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Sitecore CLI in SC10 relies on the --authority parameter which points to the identity server for authentication. There is no direct way to use the CLI without the identity server.

[refer this documentation] https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/log-in-to-a-sitecore-instance-with-sitecore-command-line-interface.html